# Why do I have to reboot my iMac and Wacom Cintiq after sleep?

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake, power

I have an iMac and a 24 inch Wacom Cintiq. When I put the iMac to sleep, it freezes and I have to restart both the iMac and the Wacom Cintiq.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with my MacBook Pro (Early 2009).

Only occurred when waking up from sleep initiated by lid close.

Workaround I used was to switch off Automatically adjust brightness (Systems Preferences -> Displays). Hasn't re-occurred since – try that and see how you go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked but just have a brightness slider bar to adjust the brightness of the screen

Comment: I can't speak for whether the answer will help you, but on an iMac the equivalent preference is in System Preferences -> Energy Saver.

Comment: Hi, Yes i switched off the automatic energy saver and it didnt work. I wrote to Wacom explaining what i had done and they said it does happen when working with an Imac and to try plugging into the usb plug on the left of my imac as that plugs right into the motherboard. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have worked either. Any other suggestions are welcome!